# Contents of file different depending on running IDE "as administrator" or not?

Tags: windows-7, runas, visual-c++

In Windows 7, using Windows Explorer, I saved a backup copy of the file C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\ATL\Include\ATLCOM.H by renaming it out of the way, and then I copied a new, slightly different file into place (as ATLCOM.H in that same directory).

Then I opened up the Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 IDE, and compiled my project (which relies upon ATLCOM.H).  I noticed that the compiled executable behaved as if I hadn't made my changes.

So then (to double check whether I actually made the changes or not) I opened the file from within the IDE.  My changes were NOT present.  But if I opened the file in some other editor, the changes ARE present.  All in all, I tried opening the file with four separate programs; except for VC++ 6.0, my changes are present when the file is opened in all of them.  Moreover, if I make another change to the file from within VC++ 6.0, and save it, the contents of the file are seemingly unaffected when viewed from within the other programs, but if I close VC++ 6.0 and reopen it, the change I made from within VC++ 6.0 is still there.  So it's getting written to disk somewhere.

Then I discovered that if I start up VC++ 6.0 via "Run As Administrator", the contents of the file look (from within VC++ 6.0) the same as they look from within the other programs.  If I start it up without "as administrator", they're different.

I'm guessing that perhaps there's something going on like Windows (or the IDE itself) merging two separate "real" directories into one virtual directory? Similarly to how Windows might merge "C:\Users\Public\Documents" and "C:\Users\Bob\Documents" into what seems like a single directory from the user's point of view? And how exactly it does that merge depends upon whether I'm running the IDE as administrator or not?

Does anyone know what is going on here? Are there some directories that I can access via Windows Explorer (or a shell prompt or whatever) that will allow me to really see the two actual files, rather than just the seemingly-merged C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\ATL\Include? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the virtual store has struck again (as Wes Sayeed answered) ! I understand why Microsoft created that feature, but it sure can cause some really confusing issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using Visual C++ 6.0.  That version of MSVC is ancient.  You are likely running into an issue with the Virtual Store feature present in Windows Vista onwards.

Here's what's happening:

The program is probably attempting to save data in its own folder under Program Files instead of your user profile folder.  In Windows 7, writes to the Program Files folder are silently and transparently redirected to the Virtual Store folder in your user profile directory.  When you select to Run as Administrator, writes to Program Files succeed and that redirection doesn't happen.

Check the following:

Look under C:\Users\\AppData\Local\VirtualStore.  Do you see a WINDOWS and a Program Files folder under there?  If so, are there files relating to VC6.0?  If so, then this is what is happening to you.

Your only solution would be to either always run as administrator or never run as administrator so that the behavior is always consistent.  You could also disable the VirtualStore feature from the local Group Policy editor (it no longer gets disabled when you turn UAC off the way it did in Windows Vista).

Alternatively, you could upgrade to a newer version of Visual C++ (which I would highly recommend because like I said, 6.0 is ancient).

Comment: this got me crazy yesterday, awesome feature from M$